# How to use reverse-i-search in C# interactive

Tags: c#

Is there a way to use `reverse-interactive-search` in `C# interactive` mode? I couldn't find it.

I'm looking for a function similar to `reverse-i-search` in `bash` or `irb`.

Comment: you may give an example of what you're looking for

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window#prefix

Answer (score 0):

There is no exactly feature `reverse-i-search` in`C # Interactive`, but you could [navigate in the history by prefix](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window#prefix).